# JavaScript popup window with scrollbars

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I have a function that pops up window in the center and I want it to have a vertical scrollbar.

```
function popUpCal()
{
    var url = "calendar_flight_maint.php";
    var width = 700;
    var height = 600;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top;
window.open(url, "subWind", windowFeatures, "POS", "toolbar=no", "scrollbars=1");
}
```

I have tried `scrollbars=yes`, `scrollbars=auto`, `scrollbars=1` but the scrollbars still aren't appearing. Is there something wrong with my code? I'm using Firefox 21.0 and I've already tested it in IE 8. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As seen in the specs for [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp), your parameters are wrong.
Try this:

```
function popUpCal()
{
    var url = "calendar_flight_maint.php";
    var width = 700;
    var height = 600;
    var left = parseInt((screen.availWidth/2) - (width/2));
    var top = parseInt((screen.availHeight/2) - (height/2));
    var windowFeatures = "width=" + width + ",height=" + height +   
        ",status,resizable,left=" + left + ",top=" + top + 
        "screenX=" + left + ",screenY=" + top + ",scrollbars=yes";

    window.open(url, "subWind", windowFeatures, "POS");
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RienNeVaPlus/mWrEU/)

Comment: did something change with the fiddle? The pop up still does not have a scroll bar. I'm having the same issue!

Comment: The URL seems to be no longer valid. But that doesn't affect the `scrollbars=yes`, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mWrEU/281/)