# How to add horizontal scrollbars to a popup-window with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to figure out how to add scrollbars to my popup-window. I've tried to add `'scrollbars = yes and scrollbars = 1'` but nothing happend. I've also tried to change the size of the popup window and the content. I want to have a scrollbar horisontally and then I will have a button so when the user clicks the button it scrolls horizontally. I manage to get the vertical scrollbar but the horizontal scrollbar never appears.

Here is my code:

```
function newWindow5() {
    window5 = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=110, height=20', 'scrollbars  = yes ', 'location = no ');
    window5.document.write('Here is a long text that could become even longer and longer and longer until...');
}

function scrollWindowHorisontal() {
    window5 = window.scrollTo(120, 100);
    window5.focus();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript popup window with scrollbars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806406/javascript-popup-window-with-scrollbars)

Comment: What browser are you using? This is important as some browsers (e.g. Firefox) display scrollbar only if the size of the content in the new window is larger than the dimensions of the new window.  You can try to force scroll bars in the css file using:                                                                    `html {
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
    }`

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in Chrome in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/7w10hqmy)

Comment: I've tried with different browsers such as Firefox and Chrome, and I've also added this in the CSS file: 'html { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; }'
The vertical scrollbars shows fine but not the horizontal which is the one I want to have since I want to use the window.scrollTo or window.scrollBy